# Get data from Win32_DiskDrive

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have I problem while I try to get disk data from `Win32_DiskDrive` via VBScript.

Here is my code:

```vb
dim objService, colDiskDrives, objItem 
dim DiskInfo, objClassProperty  

Set objService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\Root\CIMV2")
Set colDiskDrives = objService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")
DiskInfo = "Disk Drive Info" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf   

For Each objItem in colDiskDrives          
  For Each objClassProperty In objItem.Properties_  
    DiskInfo = DiskInfo & objClassProperty.Name &" = " & objClassProperty.value &vbCrLf          
  Next     
  DiskInfo = DiskInfo & "----------------------------------------------" &vbCrLf &vbCrLf 
Next   
WScript.Echo DiskInfo
```

The value of `objClassProperty.value` is always `null`.

Comment: Works for me. How do you figure the value is always `Null`? The code you posted doesn't check that anywhere, and you also never output the value of `DiskInfo`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I cant even to run this script. It show me fatal error.

Comment: You may want to include that fatal error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that the values are *always* `null`, but *sometimes* they are. Sometimes they are arrays as well, and just as `null` values, arrays cannot be printed.

Your code doesn't check for either condition. The following code does, and it checks for objects and `Nothing` values as well.

```
Dim objService, colDiskDrives, objItem 
Dim DiskInfo, objClassProperty  

Set objService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\Root\CIMV2")
Set colDiskDrives = objService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")

DiskInfo = "Disk Drive Info" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf   

For Each objItem in colDiskDrives
    For Each objClassProperty In objItem.Properties_
        DiskInfo = DiskInfo & objClassProperty.Name & " = " & StringVal(objClassProperty.value) & vbCrLf
    Next
    DiskInfo = DiskInfo & "----------------------------------------------" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Next

WScript.Echo DiskInfo

Function StringVal(value)
    If IsNull(value) Then
        StringVal = "[null]"
    ElseIf IsObject(value) Then
        If value Is Nothing Then StringVal = "[nothing]" Else StringVal = "[object]"
    ElseIf IsArray(value) Then
        StringVal = "[array]"
    Else
        StringVal = CStr(value)
    End If
End Function
```

prints this for me

```
Availability = [null]
BytesPerSector = 512
Capabilities = [array]
CapabilityDescriptions = [array]
Caption = SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series
CompressionMethod = [null]
 ... more ...
-------------------------------
```